# hiding name and port from url for multiple tomcat websites

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx, spring-boot

I'm hosting multiple websites on the same server with multiple tomcat running.

So I want to route 
www.example.com  to localhost:80/example 
and also to route
test.example.com to localhost:8082/example

I heard about a lot of scenarios: mod_jk, mod_proxy using apache http or may be nginx

but I don't know which one is the best and how to do it.

Could you please help me ?

Next step will be to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Thanks

Comment: So some guidance can be shared, what is the OS platform of choice?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it with iptables port natting.
(If your application is listening on interface eth0)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8082
```

But I prefere using nginx, Apache or HAproxy. there's a lot of tutorials on the net on how to setup a reverse proxy.